# Limit Rotation To Normal Geo Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am trying to make a scattering system and I have added wind by simply rotating the instances on the X and Y, but especially on slopes if I set the wind strength high the grass rotates too far and goes through the ground

[image: Current Node Settup]

I know I could just limit the rotation with the map range node and it works fine for that but on a steep slope it still goes through, and if I just limit the rotation to a value where it doesn't then on a flat surface it barely bends at all. I want a way to limit the rotation based on the normal and I tried just plugging the normal and the dot product of the normal into the "to max" but that doesn't work

[image: With the normal plugged in]

Does anyone know how to make it limit at the normal?
Thank you :)

Comment: Be careful what you ask for, if you limit all possible rotations to a surface, with a uniform distribution you effectively put half of instances on the surface (clamped to the nearest valid value). Otherwise simply align euler to normal, if you aligned Z, then rotate around local X 0-90°, and then rotate around normal 0-360°